# Difference between rows in R based on column values

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am new to R and learning basic stuff. I have a dataframe in R with columns like controller_id, user_id, mth_id, col_val1 till col_val100.

```
df <- data.frame('controller_id' = c('X','X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z'),
'user_id'=c('A','B','C','A','B','C','P','Q','R','P','Q','R',NA,NA),
'mth_id'=c('1393','1393','1393','1398','1398','1398','1393','1393','1393','1398','1398','1398','1393','1398'),
'col_val1' = c(5,4,6,3,1,10,12,15,18,13,19,1,5,2),
'col_val2'=c(8,12,9,2,12,5,7,9,11,4,0,7,10,5))

> df
   controller_id user_id mth_id col_val1 col_val2
1              X       A   1393        5        8
2              X       B   1393        4       12
3              X       C   1393        6        9
4              X       A   1398        3        2
5              X       B   1398        1       12
6              X       C   1398       10        5
7              Y       P   1393       12        7
8              Y       Q   1393       15        9
9              Y       R   1393       18       11
10             Y       P   1398       13        4
11             Y       Q   1398       19        0
12             Y       R   1398        1        7
13             Z    <NA>   1393        5       10
14             Z    <NA>   1398        2        5
```

What I want is to calculate the difference in col_values for each controller_id based on specific user_id, mth_id and display only those col_values which have decreased as the mth_id have increased.

For eg: for controller_id = X, we have 3 user_id as A,B,C for two different mth_ids. Code should calculate differences between col_val1 for mth_id 1398 and 1393 for all 3 users_id and if that difference is < 0 then I want an output like

```
Col_val1 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'A' has decreased from 5 to 3
```

If for a given controller_id there is no user_id associated then it should calculate the column value difference between controller_id itself.

Ideally, I want to store these output in a list/dataframe for later use. 
Also, the code is to run for approx. 900 columns present in the dataframe.

I am converting all the columns except controller_id, User_id, mth_id to numeric fields and then I'm calculating the result for each user_id (taking single column at a time) using '**data.table**'

```
> df[,4:ncol(df)] <- sapply(df[,4:ncol(df)],as.numeric)
> result_col1 <- setDT(df)[,val_diff := col_val1 - lag(col_val1,1L), by=user_id]

> result_col1
    controller_id user_id mth_id col_val1 col_val2 val_diff
  1:             X       A   1393        5        8       NA
  2:             X       B   1393        4       12       NA
  3:             X       C   1393        6        9       NA
  4:             X       A   1398        3        2       -2
  5:             X       B   1398        1       12       -3
  6:             X       C   1398       10        5        4
  7:             Y       P   1393       12        7       NA
  8:             Y       Q   1393       15        9       NA
  9:             Y       R   1393       18       11       NA
 10:             Y       P   1398       13        4        1
 11:             Y       Q   1398       19        0        4
 12:             Y       R   1398        1        7      -17
 13:             Z      NA   1393        5       10       NA
 14:             Z      NA   1398        2        5       -3
```

However, I want to achieve a similar thing at Controller_id level. I know the work flow like - pick a controller Id -- see whether we have user_id in it or not. If we have then we compare user_id column values for 1393 and 1398 and see the difference. But somehow I am not able to code this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry @agenis for not mentioning what I tried earlier. I have updated my questions with few steps that I performed.

Comment: Anyone that can help me in this? @Hack-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit base R:

```
usplit<-with(df,split(df,controller_id))

rsl<-lapply(usplit,function(dt){
  do.call("rbind",by(dt,factor(dt[,"user_id"],exclude = NULL),function(vt){
    n1=1:nrow(vt)
    cbind(vt,rbind(NA,vt[n1[-1],4:5]-vt[n1[-length(n1)],4:5]))
  }))
})

do.call("rbind",rsl)

> do.call("rbind",rsl)
        controller_id user_id mth_id col_val1 col_val2 col_val1 col_val2
X.A.1               X       A   1393        5        8       NA       NA
X.A.4               X       A   1398        3        2       -2       -6
X.B.2               X       B   1393        4       12       NA       NA
X.B.5               X       B   1398        1       12       -3        0
X.C.3               X       C   1393        6        9       NA       NA
X.C.6               X       C   1398       10        5        4       -4
Y.P.7               Y       P   1393       12        7       NA       NA
Y.P.10              Y       P   1398       13        4        1       -3
Y.Q.8               Y       Q   1393       15        9       NA       NA
Y.Q.11              Y       Q   1398       19        0        4       -9
Y.R.9               Y       R   1393       18       11       NA       NA
Y.R.12              Y       R   1398        1        7      -17       -4
Z.NA.13             Z    <NA>   1393        5       10       NA       NA
Z.NA.14             Z    <NA>   1398        2        5       -3       -5
```

If that is what you want, the last two columns are the diffs, as the final result is a `data.frame` will be easy to change.